# set of objects in JSX

Tags: javascript, jsx

Though the next code:

```
  var setA = new Set();
  var e = {};
 e['id'] = '123445';
 e['name'] = 'joe doe'
 setA.add(e);

 console.log(setA);
 var f = {};
 f['id'] = '123445';
 f['name'] = 'joe doe'
 setA.add(f);           

 console.log(setA);
```

I get that setA = {e, f}  instead of just {e}. Is there a way to avoid this? I mean, I wish setA could be just {e} after trying to add f?. Any peculiar parameter for add?

Comment: I assume this translates to ordinary sets in JavaScript. If that's the case, then no. Values are compared by identity. `e` and `f` are two different objects. You'd have to write your own set implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Felix Kling mentioned, elements in your set are compared by value if they're primitives, but by reference if they're objects. If you want objects to be deeply compared by the values of their properties, you'll have to create your own implementation, or possibly use a `Map` (where the keys would be a low collision rate hash of your object properties, and the values would be your objects) if your requirements aren't too strict.

You could also try `immutable-js`, where elements in a set are deeply compared for you.